# Who exactly was Don Eladio within cartel?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

Gustavo's revenge on Don Eladio in *Breaking-Bad* must have meant more than just personal satisfaction for Gustavo. Was Don Eladio running the entire cartel or who was he in general? I assume if he wasn't the main guy, Gustavo would not be able to live a normal life after taking out a high rank cartel member.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Please don't misuse tag styling for movie titles. That's not what it is for and the tag is already at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @TomCody - OK, they do it over on SO.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Really? Now that's weird. Do they have a meta post for this or can you show me some example question?

Comment: Maybe I was thinking of Meta.  This whole thing mighta been a brainfart.  I was wondering why none of the questions had it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Don Eladio Vuente is the head of the Ciudad Juárez Cartel. His title of Don says it all, implying royalty. But Gus' revenge was mainly personal, as Eladio was the one that had his friend killed right in front of him a long time ago. It was just very very thorough because if it wasn't, any living members of the cartel would have sought revenge.

Comment: Does this mean that Gustavo literally wiped headquarters of cartel?

Comment: @eYe the shot callers, with shots  of tequila, yes, from what I understood.